# GitHub stats is getting low

Tags: git, github

I consistently commit my code to GitHub on a daily basis; however, I have observed a decline in my overall status. Approximately 10 to 15 days ago, my rating was A+, but it gradually dropped to A, then to B, and currently stands at C+. I am seeking insights into the underlying reasons for this decline and seeking guidance on how to rectify the situation.

I am determined to identify the underlying factors contributing to this regression and proactively seek viable remedies to restore and improve my rating.

Comment: GitHub rating? Are you using some tool or plugin to calculate that? I'm not aware of GitHub assigning a rating to contributors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a big drop. I have seen a couple of different ways to measure this but the most common one I have seen is from anuraghazra. I also noticed a similar issue to you a couple of weeks ago. I know they had an issue where it would base the grade on the last 365 days instead of only the days from Jan 1st. I don't know if it has been merged yet. This could be the issue for you if you had a lot of commits earlier in the year last year. If that is not the case then you might want to see if there is an issue open in the project for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the stats provided by Anurag Hazra. The reason for this decline is that now the rating system is based on your percentile score. That means for getting an A rank you need to be in the top 37% of the total GitHub users. I simpler way to do this is to make more commits publically (now private commits are not counted) and raise issues and PRs for them.
Hope this will help.